# java How to load in a string value

Tags: java

Hello I have an application that loads in values. The values are x,y,and a string value. I want to know how to load in a  string because I only know how to o it with an integer. Take a look at this code:

```
    public static void loadStars() {
    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader   ("files/cards.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String line;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] args = line.split(" ");

                int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                String name = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

                play.s.add(new Star(x,y,name));


            }
        }

        bf.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have

```
play.s.add(new star(x,y,name));
```

I know how to load in `x` and `y` but I don't know how to load in `name`.
Please help me.

**Edit----**

In the file that is loaded in it is formatted like this:

```
x y name
```

example:

```
10 10 jack
100 500 conor
```

each star is represented by 1 line.

```
public class Star extends BasicStar {

    private Image img;

    public Star(int x, int y,String starname) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.starname = starname;

        r = new Rectangle(x, y, 3, 3);
    }

    public void tick() {

        if (r.contains(Comp.mx, Comp.my) && Comp.ml) {
            remove = true;
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        if (!displaySolar) {

            ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/planets/star.png");
            img = i2.getImage();
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array args[] is already String so you just need to change

```
String name = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
```

to

```
String name = args[2];
```

And that's it.

Comment: @user3929251  So play.s is List<Star>?

Comment: it is ArrayList(star)

Comment: the problem with this is that it only uses the name from the last line in the file so when I run it all the stars have the name of the star at the last line in the file for example

Comment: 10 10 jack (nextline) 20 50 connor  , all of the stars have the name connor

Comment: Show the constructor for Star object.

Comment: Everyting looks ok. Have you tried to run you program in debug mode? If not do it and set few debug points to find out if you get rigth values in your star object,

Comment: For netbeans: https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html For Eclipse: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: I just figured out the problem I had the string set to static which caused all the stars to have the same name. I will sill accept your answer for all the help u gave me thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void loadStars() {
        try {
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader   ("files/cards.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                String line;
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] args = line.split(" ");

                    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                    String name = args[2]; // args array contain string, no need of conversion.

                    play.s.add(new Star(x,y,name));


                }
            }

        bf.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you improve your code by using a StringTokenizer. Try This.

```
    public static void loadStars()
        throws IOException {
    String line;
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader   ("files/cards.txt"));
    try
    {
    while((line = bf.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line == null || line.trim().isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Line null!");

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
        if (tokenizer.countTokens() < 3)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Token number not valid (<= 3)");
        int x, y;
        String xx = tokenizer.nextToken(" ").trim();
        String yy = tokenizer.nextToken(" ").trim();
        String name = tokenizer.nextToken(" ").trim();
        try
        {
        x = Integer.parseInt(xx);
        }catch(ParseException e){throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Number format not valid!");}
        try
        {
        y = Integer.parseInt(yy);
        }catch(ParseException e){throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Number format not valid!");}
        play.s.add(new Star(x,y,name));
    }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException | NumberFormatException | ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array args[] is already String so you just need to change

```
String name = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

// If you are using this values anywhere else you'd do this so de GC can collects the arg[] array
String name = new String(args[2]);
```

Be aware that if you have spaces in string arguments each word will be a new argument. If you have a call like:

```
java -jar MyProgram 1 2 This is a sentence.
```

Your arg[] will be:

```
{"1", "2", "This", "is", "a", "sentence."}
```

If you need the sentence to be one String you should use apostrophes:

```
java -jar MyProgram 1 2 "This is a sentence."
```

Your arg[] will be:

```
{"1", "2", "This is a sentence."}
```